# Hay alguna forma de que el datagridview se actualice solo al hacer una actualizacion de la base de datos?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

Mi duda es porque lo intente usando un timer el cual refresque la función de llenado de Grid cada 5 segundos sin embargo se ve engorroso para el usuario en el momento de ejecución. Hay alguna forma de que al hacer un cambio en la base de datos el grid se actualice solo?

```
void LlenadoGrid()
    {
        using (MySqlConnection mysqlCon = new MySqlConnection(conStr))
        {
            mysqlCon.Open();
            MySqlCommand sqlpedpen = new MySqlCommand("select p.ped_id as ID, concat(c.cli_name,' ',c.cli_lastname) as Nombre_Cliente, pr.valor as Valor_Domicilio, p.date_reg as Fecha, p.ped_type, p.ped_entrega as Direccion, p.domi_id, c.cli_phone as Telefono, p.ped_status as Estado, p.ped_price as Valor_total, p.objects_puros from pedidos as p inner join clients as c on c.cli_phone = p.cli_phone left join product_pedidos as pr on pr.id_pt_pd = p.ped_id order by p.ped_id desc", mysqlCon);
            sqlpedpen.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            DataTable dtblpedPen = new DataTable();
            MySqlDataAdapter adapsqlpenped = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlpedpen);
            adapsqlpenped.Fill(dtblpedPen);
            dvg_Pedidos.DataSource = dtblpedPen;
            dvg_Pedidos.Columns[3].Visible = false;
            dvg_Pedidos.Columns[2].Visible = false;
            dvg_Pedidos.Columns[6].Visible = false;
            dvg_Pedidos.Columns[5].Visible = false;
            dvg_Pedidos.Columns[7].Visible = false;
            dvg_Pedidos.Columns[10].Visible = false;
            //MySqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new MySqlDataAdapter("Pedidos_ViewAll", mysqlCon);
            //sqlDa.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            //DataTable dtblPedidos = new DataTable();
            //sqlDa.Fill(dtblPedidos);
            //dvg_Pedidos.DataSource = dtblPedidos;
            //dvg_Pedidos.Columns[0].Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

De esta forma lleno el grid.

Comment: Podrias  refrescar vía  ajax y para evitar que se cargue nuevamente la página.

Comment: Agrega con que tecnologia estas implementando tu vista, windows forms, ASP:NET o WPF

Comment: Revise el tema de "Tecnología Push"